# Jasmine test: how to call through function that is called in tested function?

Tags: javascript, function, testing, jasmine

I try to test a JavaScript function with Jasmine. It looks like this:

```
show: function(){
    this.work();
    var mod = new Module();
    mod.doSomething();
}
```

I am now testing if `work()` is called in `show()`, which is no problem. But then an error occurs in `mod.doSomething()`. This makes my test fail although it actually passed. What can I do to prevent mod.doSomething to be called or at least executed. Is there something like `callThrough()` for nonused function calls?

The only idea I had was to write a global variable that can be set true or false from everywhere. Then I extend the `mod.doSomething()` function for not to be called if this variable is set true. Now I can simply set the variable to true, if I do not want this function to be executed while testing. But I think there must be a better solution. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not testable with "standard" jasmine-practices. the method `show()` should take a module as parameter.... then it would be testable with a spy on `doSomething()`...