# Javascript Jasmine Testing: Prevent tested function to call function from object that was created within tested function

Tags: javascript, testing, requirejs, jasmine, spy

I want to test a Javascript function with Jasmine that has a structure like this:

```
showEditUser: function (...) {
    // more code here...
    var editUserView = new EditUserView();
    // more code here...
    editUserView.generate(...);
}
```

`editUserView.generate()` causes an error. That does not matter because I don't want to test it. But how can I prevent it from being called?

`EditUserView` is a RequireJS Module that extends another Module called `BaseView`. The function `generate()` is defined in `BaseView`. There are other Modules that extend `BaseView` and I want all of them not to call generate while testing. How can I do that with Jasmine? It seems not to be possible with `spyOn(...).and.callFake()` because I don't have the `editUserView` Object when calling the function. Is there kind of a static way to tell Jasmine to `callFake()` the function `generate` in `BaseView`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jasmine, but using Sinon I guess one would use stubs. http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs

Comment: i think jasmine only uses spies. is this the same thing as stubs? I also think it is not possible to solve this problem with spies.

Comment: A spy is not the same as a stub. A spy only observes calls to the original function, whereas a stub would replace the original function entirely. I guess you could use sinon within jasmine, not sure how messy that would get though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "nice" way to solve this with jasmine. I think, to take a BaseView `viewObj` as parameter is a nicer coding style. It will reduce the dependencies of the method. So it don't have to know the specific `BaseView`-class, he will simply need a `viewObj` that has a `generate`-method.

```
showEditUser: function(..., viewObj) {
    // ...
    viewObj.generate(...);
}
```

Then you could create a ViewMock and put it into that function like this:

```
var viewMock = {};
viewMock.generate = jasmine.createSpy('generate() spy');
```

Then you will call it this way:

```
showEditUser(..., viewMock);
```

EDIT: [Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29745532/jasmine-test-how-to-call-through-function-that-is-called-in-tested-function/29747781#29747781)